# Install ubuntu with UEFI boot freezes on black screen after grub

Tags: 16.04, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire one Cloudbook 11. I followed advices from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715407/ubuntu-installation-on-acer-aspire-cloudbook-11) and boot options recommendation from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765570/installing-ubuntu-on-acer-cloudbook-11?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I tried using legacy mode, but I'm stuck at choosing where to install Ubuntu, because the installer doesn't show the internal drive. Tried fdisk and gparted and they don't seem to see the internal computer drive either.

I tried with UEFI, turned of secure boot. But in that case, after grub screen, I just get a blank screen, backlight is still on, but nothing happens and it stays stuck indefinitely.

Any idea why the legacy mode doesn't see the internal drive? Or why with UEFI the installer won't start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the installer is unable to detect the hard drive because it expects typical ATA storage devices, not eMMC as the cloudbook has. I run GalliumOS on a similar Lenovo N22 Chromebook, though this appears to be a device with Windows compatible firmware, not Coreboot. I'm not sure if trying out GalliumOS will bring you anywhere closer to a solution, installers like chrx are only intended for Chromebooks. Some questions how to install to eMMC exist but I havn't had time to do more research, here is one example: http://askubuntu.com/q/708156/40581